# recyclerview only changes 1 icon (favorite icon) while the data is more than 1

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to load "favorite" data in a local database (sqlite) and display it in an icon in recyclerview

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val view = holder.itemView
    val favoriteData = DatabaseHelper(view.context).loadFavoriteData() //mutablelist
    favoriteData.forEach {
        view.toggle_favorite.isChecked = data.results[position].id.toString() == it.id
    }
}
```

but when I run it, there is only one icon that changes (toggled / on) while my favorite data is more than one, only the last data from the array is taken to display in the favorite icon, like :

```
mutableListOf(.., .., .., "only the latest data is taken")
```

so please help me, thank you..

if you need full code you can find here https://github.com/rizkirakasiwi/MADE/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rizkirakasiwi/made/fragment/controller/MovieAdapter.kt

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuWSd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val view = holder.itemView
    val favoriteData = DatabaseHelper(view.context).loadFavoriteData() 
    val favorite = favoriteData.find { data.results[position].id.toString() == it.id }
    view.toggle_favorite.isChecked = (favorite != null)

}
```

Comment: @RizkiRakasiwi if I helped you, please mark my answer with a checkmark and upvote my answer :)